# Обнуление значений конкретных чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, html

Использую для блокировки чекбоксов

```
const masterCheckbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"][id="a"]');
const slaveCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][id="a_a"], input[type="checkbox"][id="a_b"]');

masterCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
  slaveCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.checked = false;
    checkbox.disabled = masterCheckbox.checked;
  });
});
```

А также для вывода значений value

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.options_form input').click(function () {
    var val = '';

    $('.options_form input').each(function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        val = val + ($(this).val() + '<br>');
      }
    });

    $('.options_val span').html(val);
  });
});

<div class="options_val">Segment: <br><span></span></div>
```

Нужно чтоб при блокировки чекбоксов, если до блокировки были отмечены и выведены значение определенных чекбоксов значение обнулялось и выводилось только значение неблокированых чекбоксхов.

Comment: в чём проблема то?

Comment: При блокировки, если до блокировки были отмечены чекбоксы а после они заблокировались их значение остается в div class="options_val, а нужно чтоб и оно обнулялось

Comment: желательно это если можно происходилов в js коде а не нагромождением div_ов